# Some kind of a bug with spring-boot version 2.0.0 snapshot

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix

```
>         2016-12-05 19:31:32.802  INFO 13700 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing
> org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@446293d:
> startup date [Mon Dec 05 19:31:32 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
> 2016-12-05 19:31:33.313  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330
> 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
> 2016-12-05 19:31:33.342  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean
> 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [class
> org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe413554]
> is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for
> example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
>     
>       .   ____          _            __ _ _  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __
>     _ \ \ \ \ ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / /
> / 
>     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/  :: Spring Boot ::  (v2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT)
>     
>     2016-12-05 19:31:34.881  INFO 13700 --- [           main] com.jci.EurekaClientApplication          : No active profile set,
> falling back to default profiles: default 2016-12-05 19:31:34.905 
> INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing
> org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@297ea53a:
> startup date [Mon Dec 05 19:31:34 IST 2016]; parent:
> org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@446293d
> 2016-12-05 19:31:37.124  WARN 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance
> @Configuration bean definition 'refreshScope' since its singleton
> instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static
> @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type:
> Consider declaring such methods as 'static'. 2016-12-05 19:31:37.594 
> INFO 13700 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope 
> : BeanFactory id=3a123b51-2c5c-3970-b385-4c599c61990b 2016-12-05
> 19:31:37.706  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330
> 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
> 2016-12-05 19:31:37.782  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean
> 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration'
> of type [class
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration]
> is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for
> example: not eligible for auto-proxying) 2016-12-05 19:31:37.882  INFO
> 13700 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker :
> Bean
> 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration'
> of type [class
> org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe413554]
> is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for
> example: not eligible for auto-proxying) 2016-12-05 19:31:38.487  INFO
> 13700 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer :
> Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8762 (http) 2016-12-05 19:31:38.506 
> INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
> 2016-12-05 19:31:38.508  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine:
> Apache Tomcat/8.5.6 2016-12-05 19:31:38.783  INFO 13700 ---
> [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       :
> Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext 2016-12-05
> 19:31:38.784  INFO 13700 --- [ost-startStop-1]
> o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext:
> initialization completed in 3879 ms 2016-12-05 19:31:39.349  INFO
> 13700 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  :
> Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/] 2016-12-05 19:31:39.358 
> INFO 13700 --- [ost-startStop-1]
> o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter:
> 'metricsFilter' to: [/*] 2016-12-05 19:31:39.358  INFO 13700 ---
> [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping
> filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*] 2016-12-05 19:31:39.358 
> INFO 13700 --- [ost-startStop-1]
> o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter:
> 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*] 2016-12-05 19:31:39.358  INFO 13700
>     --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*] 2016-12-05
> 19:31:39.359  INFO 13700 --- [ost-startStop-1]
> o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter:
> 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*] 2016-12-05 19:31:39.359  INFO 13700
>     --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*] 2016-12-05
> 19:31:39.359  INFO 13700 --- [ost-startStop-1]
> o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter:
> 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*] 2016-12-05 19:31:41.760  INFO
> 13700 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter :
> Looking for @ControllerAdvice:
> org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@297ea53a:
> startup date [Mon Dec 05 19:31:34 IST 2016]; parent:
> org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@446293d
> 2016-12-05 19:31:42.060  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped
> "{[/service-instances/{applicationName}]}" onto public
> java.util.List<org.springframework.cloud.client.ServiceInstance>
> com.jci.ServiceInstanceRestController.serviceInstancesByApplicationName(java.lang.String)
> 2016-12-05 19:31:42.381  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto
> public
> org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String,
> java.lang.Object>>
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
> 2016-12-05 19:31:42.381  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped
> "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public
> org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
> 2016-12-05 19:31:42.440  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path
> [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class
> org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
> 2016-12-05 19:31:42.440  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto
> handler of type [class
> org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
> 2016-12-05 19:31:42.517  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path
> [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class
> org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
> 2016-12-05 19:31:44.564  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/info ||
> /info.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public
> java.lang.Object
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
> 2016-12-05 19:31:44.565  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/heapdump ||
> /heapdump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/octet-stream]}"
> onto public void
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HeapdumpMvcEndpoint.invoke(boolean,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
> throws java.io.IOException,javax.servlet.ServletException 2016-12-05
> 19:31:44.566  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/features ||
> /features.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto
> public java.lang.Object
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
> 2016-12-05 19:31:44.567  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/dump ||
> /dump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public
> java.lang.Object
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
> 2016-12-05 19:31:44.573  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped
> "{[/loggers/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}"
> onto public java.lang.Object
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint.get(java.lang.String)
> 2016-12-05 19:31:44.574  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped
> "{[/loggers/{name:.*}],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json]}"
> onto public java.lang.Object
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint.set(java.lang.String,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,
> java.lang.String>) 2016-12-05 19:31:44.574  INFO 13700 --- [          
> main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/loggers ||
> /loggers.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public
> java.lang.Object
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
> 2016-12-05 19:31:44.575  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/refresh ||
> /refresh.json],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object
> org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
> 2016-12-05 19:31:44.577  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/configprops ||
> /configprops.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto
> public java.lang.Object
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
> 2016-12-05 19:31:44.578  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/restart ||
> /restart.json],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object
> org.springframework.cloud.context.restart.RestartMvcEndpoint.invoke()
> 2016-12-05 19:31:44.582  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped
> "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}"
> onto public java.lang.Object
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
> 2016-12-05 19:31:44.582  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics ||
> /metrics.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public
> java.lang.Object
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
> 2016-12-05 19:31:44.585  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mappings ||
> /mappings.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto
> public java.lang.Object
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
> 2016-12-05 19:31:44.586  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/pause ||
> /pause.json],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object
> org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
> 2016-12-05 19:31:44.588  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/beans ||
> /beans.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public
> java.lang.Object
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
> 2016-12-05 19:31:44.591  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/resume ||
> /resume.json],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object
> org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
> 2016-12-05 19:31:44.592  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped
> "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto
> public java.lang.Object
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
> 2016-12-05 19:31:44.593  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env ||
> /env.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public
> java.lang.Object
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
> 2016-12-05 19:31:44.594  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/archaius ||
> /archaius.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto
> public java.lang.Object
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
> 2016-12-05 19:31:44.595  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/autoconfig ||
> /autoconfig.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto
> public java.lang.Object
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
> 2016-12-05 19:31:44.596  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped
> "{[/env],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object
> org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManagerMvcEndpoint.value(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,
> java.lang.String>) 2016-12-05 19:31:44.596  INFO 13700 --- [          
> main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped
> "{[/env/reset],methods=[POST]}" onto public
> java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>
> org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManagerMvcEndpoint.reset()
> 2016-12-05 19:31:44.598  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/trace ||
> /trace.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public
> java.lang.Object
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
> 2016-12-05 19:31:44.599  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/health ||
> /health.json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public
> java.lang.Object
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(java.security.Principal)
> 2016-12-05 19:31:44.869  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.ui.freemarker.SpringTemplateLoader   : SpringTemplateLoader for
> FreeMarker: using resource loader
> [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@297ea53a:
> startup date [Mon Dec 05 19:31:34 IST 2016]; parent:
> org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@446293d]
> and template loader path [classpath:/templates/] 2016-12-05
> 19:31:44.871  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.w.s.v.f.FreeMarkerConfigurer         : ClassTemplateLoader for
> Spring macros added to FreeMarker configuration 2016-12-05
> 19:31:45.075  WARN 13700 --- [           main]
> ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.archaius.ArchaiusAutoConfiguration':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field
> 'externalConfigurations'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'java.util.List<org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration>'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> 2016-12-05 19:31:45.083  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed
> beans on shutdown 2016-12-05 19:31:45.093  INFO 13700 --- [          
> main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service
> Tomcat 2016-12-05 19:31:45.139  INFO 13700 --- [           main]
> utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 
>     
>     Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug'
> enabled. 2016-12-05 19:31:45.350 ERROR 13700 --- [           main]
> o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>     
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name
> 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.archaius.ArchaiusAutoConfiguration':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field
> 'externalConfigurations'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'java.util.List<org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration>'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:577)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:362)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1231)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:749)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
> ~[spring-context-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
> ~[spring-context-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]   at
> org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
> ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]  at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:736)
> [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]   at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
> [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]   at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
> [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]   at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1161)
> [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]   at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1150)
> [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]   at
> com.jci.EurekaClientApplication.main(EurekaClientApplication.java:20)
> [classes/:na] Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> **'java.util.List<org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration>**'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1462)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1092)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:574)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]     ... 19
> common frames omitted
```

The code was working fine a day ago but suddenly it started to throw a bean creation exception. First I thought the problem may be some autowired bean and autoconfiguration feature of spring, but it doesn't work. Finally I changed the version of it to it's older version and magically it starts working.

The reason for posting the question is that I want to know the real problem  behind these exception. Is there any bug in the latest version or something?

Comment: Spring Boot 2.0.0 is still a work in progress (hence the snapshot) so you can expect things to break... Use a final like (1.4.2) instead of unreleased snapshots (which themselves use snapshots/milestone releases).

Comment: I am not sure the Spring Cloud team has started to compile against Spring 5 yet. You should ask them.